# MySQL can't return kanji into variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

i can't get kanji character outside MySQL, kanjis are shown from phpmyadmin normally but when dragged out into variable it can't, they became ???, already try to add

```
          <meta charset=utf-8 />
```

but still doesn't work. here's part of my code

```
    <?php
        include_once('class/word.php');
        include_once('conn/connection.php');
        $conn = get_koneksi();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
                $stm= $conn -> prepare($sql);
        $stm -> bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['id']);
        $stm-> execute();
        if ($stm-> rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $stm-> fetch();
          #this result nothing
            echo "<script>alert(".$row['kanji'].");</script>";
           $item = new word($row['id'],$row['word'],$row['kanji'],$row['length']);
          #this result undefined -> $item->getKanji() is blank in alert
            echo "<script>alert(".$item->getKanji().");</script>";
          #this result ???? character instead kanjis
          echo "<div style='width:700px;position:absolute;'><h1>".$item->getKanji()."</h1></div>";
        }else echo "No Data Found !";
    ?>
```

How to solve this still in PDO usage ?

Comment: Your kanjis aren't in phpmyadmin: they're in a MySQL database. phpmyadmin is just a front end gui tool for working with data in a MySQL database

Comment: [utf-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: thank you sir, this one point me to the answer